# If the bug is fixed and the post is not yet changed to status-completed, how can I notify to moderator?

Tags: support, tags, moderators, per-site-meta

If there was a post reported with [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag months or even years ago on Meta Stack Exchange or a per-site meta, and now the bug is fixed and working fine, but nobody has changed the status to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), how can I notify someone?

- I can simply **add a comment** to the post saying the bug is fixed, @-mention one of the moderators - but I feel this adds unwanted noise to the post.
- I can **flag** the question with **in need of moderator intervention** to add my comments about the bug, it was fixed.

What is the correct way to notify about the post to the moderator?

Comment: I'd recommend just pinging a mod in chat, but I don't see anything wring with flagging for mod attention.

Comment: I would say flag, but from personal experience, you might wait for weeks and months here on MSE, so it's pointless. So I don't do it anymore myself.

Comment: An @-mention won't work if the person you mentioned hasn't interacted with the post (wrote it, commented on it, edited it.)